# embeddable array type of schema in python-eve

Tags: python, dictionary, eve

I know we can make a resource embeddable in another resource, however below schema does not seems to be working? what is the right way to make an array of resources embeddable in another resource?

```
outer = {
   'type': 'dict',
   'schema': {
       'inner': {
           'type': 'list',
            'schema': {
                'type': 'objectid',
                'required': True,
                'data_relation': {
                    'resource': 'other_resources',
                    'embeddable': True,
            },
        },
    },
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently not supported:

> Currenly we only support a single layer of embedding, i.e. `/emails?embedded={"author": 1}` but not `/emails?embedded={"author.friends": 1}`.

However, there's an active pull request right now ([Add support for two layers of document embedding](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/pull/280)) which tries to address this limitation.